# $f:[0,1]\times Y\to \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function, prove $I_f(y)=\int_0^1f(x,y)dx$ is continuous. $Y$ is metric space

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, analysis

Let $f:[0,1]\times Y\to \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function where $Y$ is a metric space. Now let $I_f(y):Y\to \mathbb{R}$ be the function $$I_f(y)=\int_0^1f(x,y)dx$$then prove that $I_f(y)$ is continuous on $Y$.

I tried this problem first fixing $y$.  If we fix $y$ then $g(x)=f(x,y)$ is continuous on $[0,1]$ , hence it is uniformly continuous. Therefore $\forall\ \epsilon >0\ \exists \ \delta>0$ such that  $$|x-x'|<\delta\implies |f(x,y)-f(x',y)|<\epsilon$$Suppose we want to prove continuity at $y$. Now since $f$ is continuous for every $\epsilon>0$ there exists $\delta>0$ such that $|h|<\delta\implies |f(x,y+h)-f(x,y)|<\epsilon$.

I want to show $|f(x,y+h)-f(x,y)|<\epsilon$ for all $x\in [0,1]$ and for $|h|<\delta$ where $\delta>0$ so that $$\int_0^1|f(x,y+h)-f(x,y)|dx< \int_0^1\epsilon\, dx=\epsilon$$

But i cant not do anything further with this. How to do this

Comment: Perhaps take a sequence $y_k \to y$, notice that $B=\{y_k\}_k \cup \{y\}$ is compact. Then $[0,1] \times B$ is compact.